# Does shuffle() function makes query faster?

Tags: php

I have two tables with more than 150000 rows of numbers, and I have this code:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
$negative = strlen($q);
$reverse = strrev($q);
while ($a = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
    {
    if ($reverse==substr($a[$i],-$negative,strlen($q)))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint=$a[$i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
echo $hint . "\t";
}
```

This query takes 27 seconds to return the results, and I wanted to shuffle all the results, but when I added shuffle() function like this:

```
while ($a = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
shuffle($a);
```

The performance changed amazingly, now it takes only two seconds to return the results, and I have tried many times it's the same.
Does it make faster?

Comment: I don't I dont belive it too, but when i delete it, the performance slows down again.

Comment: More code doing more work == faster by orders of magnitude. Uhm... I'd like some more conclusive, reproducible proof for that, please.

Comment: Have you verified that the output is actually the same with the shuffle() in place as without? And that the while loop is iterated the same number of times?

Comment: The output is the same as before but it's not shuflles the numbers

Comment: I can't quite make out exactly what's going on underneath here at the moment, but I think I know what the root cause is - try using `mysql_fetch_row()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` and get rid of the `shuffle()` and I *think* you'll find it is just as fast. I think the mixed indexed/associative array that `mysql_fetch_array()` returns is screwing with your `for` loop, and the `shuffle()` call converts the array to an indexed array which sorts the problem out.

Comment: @DaveRandom I was toying with thoughts it may be something to do with `MYSQL_BOTH` being default fetch method. In theory it should be spamming undefined index errors since `count($a)` will include the assoc rows. The fact `count` has to be evaluated every iteration is definitely hitting performance. - Hah, you edited while I was typing :)

Comment: @Leigh Indeed, but I'm guessing the OP is probably working on a server with error reporting set pretty low (as so many of them seem to be) or the question would mention it - maybe that's a foolish assumption. I actually had not spotted the `count()` as a loop condition and indeed this probably will impact performance over 150000 iterations - but by no more than a couple of hundred ms. I can't believe the above code is producing *useful* output either way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns an array with both numeric and string keys, so it's an associative array, which requires hashing for all lookups. `shuffle` discards all the keys, converting it into an indexed array, which can be accessed more efficiently.

Note that when you do this, the shuffled row has two elements for each column returned, one from the numeric key and another from the named key. You should use `mysql_fetch_row` or `mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM)` to prevent this problem. If you do this, the code without the shuffle will be fast, too.

Comment: As for the *why*. It's almost definitely because half of the time `NOTICE` errors are being generated because of undefined index access. Using `count` as an upper bound for `$i`, but having 50% associative array keys, not all numeric means that 50% of the time `$a[$i]` will not exist. Regardless of whether they are being reported, the generation of `NOTICE` errors will slow down the script.

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely not. It is likely that your SQL server cached the result, thus being faster the second time around.

Comment: but when I delete it, the query takes 27 seconds again to return the results

Comment: Hmm, disregard this answer then.